ResponseEntity Error Handling in Java Spring Boot
In my core controller method, I'm sending a ResponseEntity with status 500
CORE CONTROLLER
@PostMapping("/getGroupDefinitions")
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseDTO> getGroupDefinition(@RequestBody GetGroupDefinitionRequestDao getGroupDefinitionRequestDao) {
        String endPoint = "/getGroupDefinitions";
        Timestamp landingTime = Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.now());
        log.info("getGroupDefinitionRequestDao: {}", getGroupDefinitionRequestDao.toString());
        try {
            List<PimGroupDefinitionProjection> response = pimGroupDefinitionService.getGroupDefinitions(getGroupDefinitionRequestDao);
            return ResponseUtil.sendResponse(
                    response,
                    landingTime,
                    HttpStatus.OK,
                    200,
                    RequestMethod.POST.name(),
                    endPoint
            );
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error while getting Group Definitions: {}", (Object) e.getStackTrace());
            ResponseEntity<ResponseDTO> errorResponse = ResponseUtil.sendErrorResponse(
                    "GET_GROUP_DEFINITIONS_ERROR",
                    "Error while getting group definitions, " + e.getMessage(),
                    landingTime,
                    HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
                    500
            );
            log.error("Error while getting Group Definitions: {}", errorResponse);
            return errorResponse;
        }
    }

BFF CONTROLLER
@ActivityLogging
    @PostMapping("/getGroupDefinitions")
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseDTO> getGroupDefinitions(@RequestBody GetGroupDefinitionsRequestDao getGroupDefinitionsRequestDao, HttpServletRequest request) {
        String endPoint = "/getGroupDefinitions";
        log.info(endPoint + "request {}", getGroupDefinitionsRequestDao);
        Timestamp landingTime = Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.now());
        try {
            getGroupDefinitionsCoreResponse = pimCoreClient.getGroupDefinitions(getGroupDefinitionsRequestDao);
            if (getGroupDefinitionsCoreResponse.getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.OK) {
                throw new Exception(Objects.requireNonNull(getGroupDefinitionsCoreResponse.getBody()).getResponseMessage().getMessage());
            }
            return ResponseUtil.sendResponse(
                    Objects.requireNonNull(getGroupDefinitionsCoreResponse.getBody()).getResponseData(),
                    landingTime,
                    HttpStatus.OK,
                    200,
                    "POST",
                    endPoint
            );
        } catch (UnauthorizedException e) {
            log.error(LocalExceptionMessage.MSG_UNAUTHORIZED_EX + LocalExceptionMessage.MSG_MESSAGE + e.getMessage());
            return ResponseUtil.sendErrorResponse(
                    "U",
                    e.getMessage(),
                    landingTime,
                    HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED,
                    401
            );
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(LocalExceptionMessage.MSG_EX_FOUND + LocalExceptionMessage.MSG_MESSAGE + e.getMessage());
            return ResponseUtil.sendErrorResponse(
                    "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
                    e.getMessage(),
                    landingTime,
                    HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
                    500
            );
        }
    }
}



So in my bff controller,  will the status of the coreResponse be checked in the if statement or it will run into the catch block?
When i debug it, after the pimGroupDefinitionService.getGroupDefinitions(getGroupDefinitionRequestDao) is called it is running into catch statement
I want to understand how a ResponseEntity with status 500 will be handled.
I'm using feign for microservice communication between bff and core

I honestly didn't understand anything. You just provided the code snippets, not complete methods, so I don't understand what calles what. Please provide the complete controller code.

For undestanding how feign error handled:
https://www.baeldung.com/java-feign-client-exception-handling
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55020389/spring-feign-client-exception-handling
